# pandas read_table gives single column with JSON data

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to deal with a larger file, and I have used the get_chunk method, but the does not load properly.

## What I tried

```
def load_data():
    reader = pd.read_table('/Users/fiz/Desktop/xad', iterator=True,encoding='utf-8')
    loop = True
    chunkSize = 10000
    chunks = []
    while loop:
       try:
          chunk = reader.get_chunk(chunkSize)
          chunks.append(chunk)
          print(chunk)

       except StopIteration:
          loop = False
          print("Iteration is stopped.")
    df = pd.concat(chunks, ignore_index=True)
```

## Gives:

```
{"_index":"pos_journals-2017.03.24","_type":"pos_journals","_id":"AVr_peEqanqtRFPuszUt","_score":null,"_source": {"message":"Chk 4040                   Gst 0\r\n1005 Yangshuying          PCWS02\r\nCE:   1005 CC:      0 TC:      0\r\nTrn 8704          24Mar'17 17:28\r\n--------------------------------\r\n    To Go       \r\n      SR:6010381353541922\r\n           SR:ONLINE\r\n  1 Mocha Ice V         37.00\r\n    Cash               102.00\r\n    Subtotal            37.00\r\n    Paid                37.00\r\n    Change Due          65.00\r\n================================","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2017-03-24T09:28:56.787Z","type":"pos_journals","count":1,"beat":{"hostname":"S24376","name":"S24376"},"source":"d:\\MICROS\\Res\\Pos\\Journals\\POS02.txt","offset":40621,"input_type":"log","fields":null,"host":"S24376","tags":["beats_input_codec_plain_applied"]},"fields":{"@timestamp":[1490347736787]},"highlight":{"message":["Chk 4040                   Gst 0\r\n1005 Yangshuying          PCWS02\r\nCE:   1005 CC:      0 TC:      0\r\nTrn 8704          24Mar'17 17:28\r\n--------------------------------\r\n    To Go       \r\n      SR:6010381353541922\r\n           SR:ONLINE\r\n  1 Mocha Ice V         37.00\r\n    @kibana-highlighted-field@Cash@/kibana-highlighted-field@               102.00\r\n    Subtotal            37.00\r\n    Paid                37.00\r\n    Change Due          65.00\r\n================================"]},"sort":[1490347736787]}

 0   {"_index":"pos_journals-2017.03.24","_type":"p...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 1   {"_index":"pos_journals-2017.03.24","_type":"p...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 2   {"_index":"pos_journals-2017.03.24","_type":"p...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 3   {"_index":"pos_journals-2017.03.24","_type":"p...
```

## Desired output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Crm4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your data file is JSON.

Try the [`pandas.read_json` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html)

It also looks like the data is in the `'records'` orientation, so something like:

```
pd.read_json('/Users/fiz/Desktop/xad', orient='records', encoding='utf-8')
```

May be a good place to start.

Sadly the `read_json` method does not seem to support chunking.